# Cloudscraper does not solve normal JS check Cloudflare challenge

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, cloudflare, anti-bot

I´m using the cloudscraper package ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/), [Github](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper)) for web requests on a site that is protected with **Cloudflare**.

I am well aware there are *challenges* that can´t be solved yet with this package, particularly the "v2 challenges" with recaptchas and so on.

However, for me, the package seems to not work at all. When I do a *GET* request with

```
s.get(my_url)
```

where s is a Cloudscraper session object, I often get a HTML page with this title: ***"Attention Required! | Cloudflare"***.
This is the standard Cloudflare Javascript challenge, which just checks whether the *browser supports JS*.

I don´t know why this happens. I made sure that

- I have a 'realistic' User agent set, with Chrome set as browser argument in the

  cloudscraper.CloudScraper()
  constructor.
- request are timed and not too fast, I wait between requests
- I have all the package **requirements** installed, meaning besides cloudscraper itself, requests, requests-toolbelt, and js2py as *engine*.

There is no issues section on the Github repo.

The Javascript check is the simplest challenge that Cloudflare can throw at us. Still, this package, which has the sole purpose of solving some Cloudflare challenges, fails to even get past this simple check.

What am I overlooking? Cloudflare makes web automation a nightmare...

EDIT: Also, the Cloudflare page says 'Please enable Cookies and reload the page.' although normally cookies are automatically accepted by the request session´s RequestsCookieJar.